# C++ why is there a segmentation fault in my pointer selection sort?

Tags: c++, sorting, pointers, selection-sort

Below is my c++ code. I am trying to implement a selection sort using pointers (start and end). The code compiles, but I am getting a segmentation fault before it will sort the random generated list (currently only prints the random numbers).

Any help as to why this is and how to fix it would be greatly appreciated.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void selectionSort(int *start, int *stop) {
   for (int i = *start; i < *stop - 1; ++i) {
     int min = i;
       for (int j = i + 1; j < *stop; ++j) {
         if ((&start[0])[j] < (&start[0])[min])
            min = j;
         }
     swap((&start[0])[i], (&start[0])[min]);
   }
}


int main()
{
  int size = 10;
    int* data = new int[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
   {
      data[i] = rand() % size;
    }
    for (int k = 0; k < size; k++)
    {
      cout << data[k] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
    selectionSort(data, data+size);
    for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
    {
      cout << data[j+1] << " ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Careful with how you tag. Your code example is so clearly not C that you will annoy some of the C programmers the C tag attracts.

Comment: what is `j+1` when `j` is `size-1`?

Comment: Are you required to use pointers here? C++'s references should be able to handle what you are doing with far less fuss.

Comment: `for (int i = *start;` no that's not how you traverse an array. Write a separate `min` function, debug and test it. Then use one in your `sort`

Comment: ah sorry about the c tag, this is my first post. Yes, pointers for start and end are required

Comment: `swap((&start[0])[i], (&start[0])[min]);` is oddly phrased. `&start[0]` is the same thing as `start`, so you could write (and most people would expect to read) `swap(start[i], start[min]);`

Comment: Sidenote: the `swap` being used is likely `std::swap` and neither of the headers that provides `std::swap`, `<algorithm>` and `<utility>` are included in this program. Likely they are being pulled in by `<iostream>`, but you can't always count on this. A different compiler may raise an error that `std::swap` cannot be found. It really sucks when one of these different compilers turns out to be the one used by the person marking the assignment. The rule of thumb is to always include all of headers required by the functions and data structures you use n order to prevent nasty surprises.

Comment: Micronag: be careful with indentation. To the casual reader, `if ((&start[0])[j] < (&start[0])[min])` appears to have a close brace. Someone, including you, could drop in the extra `}` that seems to be missing before `swap((&start[0])[i], (&start[0])[min]);`. My suggestion to beginning programmers is to always use the optional braces and to consider using the [Allman indentation style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style#Allman_style) because the way it lines up the braces makes it really easy to catch scoping errors and misplaced brackets..

Comment: thanks for that @user4581301, yes i will need to spend some time getting that indenting right

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The general logic in your function is in the right direction. However, you seem to be confused between values of the elements of the array and the indexing used to access the elements of the array.

The line

```
for (int i = *start; i < *stop - 1; ++i)
```

shows the first signs of the confusion.

1. You are initializing `i` with the value of the first element of the array and incrementing the value in the subsequent iterations of the loop. That is not correct. Incrementing the value of the first element of the array does not make logical sense.
2. `*stop` causes undefined behavior since `stop` points to a place one past the last valid element.

You need to use `int* i`, `int* j`, and `int* min` to properly sort the elements. That also means updating almost the entire function accordingly. Here's an updated function that works for me.

```
void selectionSort(int *start, int *stop) {
   for (int* i = start; i < (stop - 1); ++i) {
      int* min = i;
      for (int* j = i + 1; j < stop; ++j) {
         if (*j < *min)
         {
            min = j;
         }
      }
      swap(*i, *min);
   }
}
```

Also, the following lines in `main` are not correct. You end up accessing the array using an out of bounds index.

```
for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
{
   cout << data[j+1] << " ";
}
```

Replace them by

```
for (int k = 0; k < size; k++)
{
   cout << data[k] << " ";
}
```

Comment: This is a great answer, When pointers are a new concept, the rush to dereference, to return to a familiar domain, is understandable, but this mentality causes an unnecessary cascade of problems. A perusal of the STL `<algorithm>` interfaces would benefit the OP.